# Exportar a excel Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola a todos estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto que requiere exportar los datos de una tabla a Excel, pero cuando genera y se descarga el Excel al momento de abrir el archivo me genera un error , es una tabla HTML. Si alguien conoce una mejor forma de exportar archivos a Excel se los agradecería.

```
<script>
    function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    
    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'Ventas_Generales.xls';
    
    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['ufeff', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;
    
        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
}
    </script>
```

Adjunto imagen del error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] y agregar un ejemplo de tabla (`html`) con la que da error?

Comment: No estoy seguro de si el tipo de archivo que estás declarando en `dataType` es el correcto. Usualmente se usa `text/csv`. Pero puedo estar equivocado. ¿Has probado guardar como `csv`?